# How can I create a negation of the sentence?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

What are some ways that I can generate the negation of a sentence such that the output sentence reflects the negation of original sentence?

If the sentence is: `That is an apple.`

Then, the expected negation could be: `That is not an apple.`

Another example:

```
Sentence: Rita is so hot.
Negation: Rita is boring.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look in to [Style Transfer](https://github.com/fuzhenxin/Style-Transfer-in-Text). This is an active field of research.